# Problem with horizontal Scrollbar in treeview tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I've got problem with horizontall Scrollbar. When I want to add another column or make the column wider the horizontal scrollbar should do the trick insted of making the treeview wider. I tried to add frame but it didn't help and it's not about making scrollbar wider or thinner treeview but the scrollbar should help shorten to "shorten" the treeview. The code below:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
fr = Frame(root)
fr.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,columnspan=5)
scrollb2 = ttk.Scrollbar(fr,orient="horizontal")
scrollb = ttk.Scrollbar(fr)
tree2 = ttk.Treeview(fr,height=12)
tree2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=17,columnspan=5,sticky="nsew")
scrollb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E,ipady=110,columnspan=5)
tree2.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollb.set)
scrollb.config(command=tree2.yview)
scrollb2.grid(row=2, column=0,ipadx=390,rowspan=1,sticky=S,columnspan=5)
tree2.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollb2.set)
scrollb2.config(command=tree2.xview)

tree2["columns"]=("one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","seven")
tree2["show"]="heading" 
for col in tree2["columns"]: 
      tree2.column(col, width=10)
tree2.update() 
tree2.column("one",width=120)
tree2.column("two",width=220)
tree2.column("three",width=110)
tree2.column("four",width=90)
tree2.column("five",width=110)
tree2.column("six",width=110)
tree2.column("seven",width=70)
tree2.column("seven",width=70)
tree2.heading("one",text="ISBN")
tree2.heading("two", text="Tytuł")
tree2.heading("three", text="Autor")
tree2.heading("four", text="Rok wydania")
tree2.heading("five", text="Miejsce wydania")
tree2.heading("six", text="Wydawnictwo")
tree2.heading("seven", text="Ilość stron")
tree2.heading("seven", text="Ilość stron")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try moving `tree2["show"]="heading"` to after the line `tree2["columns"]=...`.  After that, setting all the column widths to a small value, like `for col in tree2["columns"]: tree2.column(col, 10)` followed by `tree2.update()`.  And then you can set the column widths back to whatever you want.

Comment: It raised TclError: unknown option "-100"

Comment: I set columns width in this way= tree2.column("one",width=100,minwidth=160)
tree2.column("two",width=300,minwidth=350)
tree2.column("three",width=110,minwidth=200)..........

Comment: I tried this [code](https://pastebin.com/5XQTLjdV) based on yours.

Comment: I edited the code above, and got this error. Maybe I did sth wrong, could you check it?

Comment: `tree2.column(col, 10)` should be `tree2.column(col, width=10)`.  And `tree2.update()` should be after the for loop.

Comment: tree2.column(col,width=10)

Comment: And add `sticky='nsew'` to `tree2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=17,columnspan=5)`.  I have updated your code.